# How do I add a picture of myself at the login screen?

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to add a image of myself in the login screen (when user credentials are asked). How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't catch your last comment. You can take a picture with the webcam with Photo Booth (Applications>Photo Booth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences>Users & Groups. Click on your account name in the sidebar and you'll have the option to change your picture if you mouseover it in the right pane and click edit picture.
[image: Edit picture]

Answer (score 2):

To edit the image associated with your login go to **System Preferences > Users & Groups**, click on your account in the left hand pane,  click on the image in the *Password* tab on the right, then select *Edit Image…*.

[image: image of Password Tab of User Account in Users & Groups Preferences Pane]

You also have to be certain that *Display login window as* ***List of Users*** is selected under *Login Options* of the *Users & Groups* preferences pane.

[image: image of Login Options for Users & Groups preferences pane]